# VS code's remote explorer keeps on asking for password even though I have provided my ssh keys to the remote server

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, ssh, remote-server

[image: Enter password for root@164.52.202.117]

I have a remote server (*Cloud GPU*) running at **164.52.203.148** (*e2enetworks*), where I have provided my ssh key (which I had generated on cmd using `ssh-keygen`).

Now when I go to the terminal and write `ssh root@164.52.203.148`, it connects to the server. But when I open the remote explorer in *VScode* and try to connect it asks for a password, as shown in the above image:

> Enter password for root@164.52.202.117

I don't know what this second ip address means as it is not the ip address of the remote server I am trying to connect.

Regardless I would like to be connected through the remote explorer without having asked for a password.

PS: I have looked around and many people seem to having the same issue, the fix has something to do with the config file in my ssh folder, but because the answers were not very clear I couldn't fix it.

Thanks!